# Minute-based stock chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Is there any way to make Excel stock chart show time on minute basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to emulate stock chart with per-minute axis using other types of charts: http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/candlestick-alternative-individually-colored-up-down-bars/